How is lintVitalRelease different from lint and why isn't it running?
In my Android app, ./gradlew lint and ./gradlew check (which triggers lint) both pass. However, as I discovered from a CodeQL check, ./gradlew lintVitalRelease does not pass. It's an easy enough error to fix, Error: @+id/histogram is not a sibling in the same ConstraintLayout [NotSibling], but I don't understand why the normal lint, which does find many other issues, didn't find this issue. What is the difference between these two lint commands?
Further, I added in my app's build.gradle.kts:
tasks.named("check") {
    dependsOn("lintVitalRelease")
}

to make this additional checking run on check, but everything still passes on check while failing on lintVitalRelease, even though when I run ./gradlew check --dry-run, it looks like it should be running lintVitalRelease too. What's going on here?
